# How to show that $ \sum_{d/n} \mu^{2}(d)/\phi(d) = n/\phi(n)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, totient-function

$\forall n, n\in\mathbb{N}$ $\frac{n}{\phi{(n)}} = \sum_{d/n} \frac{\mu^{2}(d)}{\phi(d)}$

Where $\mu$ is the Möbius function.

Comment: i dont know how can i change $\mu^{2}(d)$...

Comment: i dont know how can i change $\mu^{2}(d)$... i do know that $\frac{n}{\phi(n)} = \frac{\sum_{d/n} \phi(d)}{\sum_{d/n} \mu(d)\frac{n}{d}}$

Comment: OK, that helps. See the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $n = p_1^{r_1} \cdots p_k^{r_k}$ with the $p_i$ distinct primes and $r_i > 0$. Then $\mu(d)^2$ is $1$ if $d$ is square-free and $0$ otherwise, so
\begin{align*}
\sum_{d | n} \frac{\mu(d)^2}{\phi(d)}
 &= \sum_{n_i = 0, 1} \phi\left(p_1^{n_1} \cdots p_k^{n_k}\right)^{-1} \\
 &= \sum_{n_i = 0, 1} \phi\left(p_1^{n_1}\right)^{-1} \cdots \phi\left(p_k^{n_k}\right)^{-1} \\
 &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{p_1 - 1}\right) \cdots \left(1 + \frac{1}{p_k - 1}\right) \\
 &= \frac{p_1}{p_1 - 1} \cdots \frac{p_k}{p_k - 1} \\
 &= \frac{n}{\phi(n)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: i dont get why $\sum_{n_i = 0, 1} \phi\left(p_1^{n_1}\right)^{-1} \cdots \phi\left(p_k^{n_k}\right)^{-1}
 = \left(1 + \frac{1}{p_1 - 1}\right) \cdots \left(1 + \frac{1}{p_k - 1}\right)$

Comment: The sum is just $\left(\phi(1)^{-1} + \phi(p_1)^{-1}\right) \cdots \left(\phi(1)^{-1} + \phi(p_k)^{-1}\right)$.

Comment: Got it!!!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

**A start:** The functions $\mu^2$, $\varphi$, and the identity function $f(n)=n$ are **multiplicative**.

Also, if $g$ is multiplicative, then $h(n)=\sum_{d|n}g(d)$ is multiplicative.

So we only need to establish the result for $n$ of the form $p^k$, where $p$ is prime. That will be straightforward.